# OpenGL MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, uniform

So, I am working with a shader that has several 4D vector arrays which are dynamically sized at compile time. These arrays can be set to quite large lengths via another part of the code (up to 512 elements). However, because of fragment uniform limits, on some machines and with certain compile options, it's not possible to make the arrays this long without the shader failing.

Now, what I would like to do (and it is appropriate in the circumstances) is to cap these arrays such that these bounds are never exceeded. It's fine if the arrays aren't quite as long as the user intended sometimes, just as long as they don't break.

I am aware that MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS is the field I need to look at, compared to the component sizes of each array element (so a vec4 array of length 10 would, I believe, take up 40 components). If I understand this right, this limit is global to the shader, and also applies to non-array uniforms too. However, one thing is stumping me:

Samplers.

How much, if any, do samplers use of this component count? If I'm going to successfully implement an upper limit on array size, I need an accurate count for when exactly an array would be "too big", so that I can truncate it just below that point. I've looked all over but I can't seem to find any information on how many components a sampler would take. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I would advise you not to push the limits of default uniforms that far. It'd be better to just use UBOs/SSBOs if you need that many uniforms.

Comment: I don't have that option. The system I'm working with only supports OpenGL 2, which does not support either of those features.

Comment: A sampler uniform behaves like a single-component integer uniform from the API side, so it probably counts as that for the component count? This is purely conjecture though.

Comment: My tests suggest that on my hardware it takes more than 4 components, though exactly how many I can't quite determine.